# ember-cli import datatables

Tags: ember.js, datatables, ember-cli

I want to use Ember-cli witch imports jquery-dataTables.

At `Brocfile.js` ,I import the files like this:

```
app.import('bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
app.import('bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');
```

And I generate a component data-wrapper, in `data-wrapper.js`,like follow:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'table',
  classNames: ['table','table-striped','table-bordered','dataTable'],
  _didInsertElement: function() {

    var $ = Ember.$;
    $().dataTable ({

    });
  }.on('didInsertElement')
});
```

At `data-wrapper.hbs`,like follow:

```
{{yield}}
```

and at `application.hbs`, like this

```
{{#data-wrapper}}
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>...</tbody>
{{/data-wrapper}}
```

but, when I run the project, the javascript controller shows the wrong `uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` at the line

```
$().dataTable ({
})
```

Comment: To access the view's element you need to use `this.$()` .

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to call a function on the components jquery element use the `$` method.

Like:

```
_didInsertElement: function() {
  this.$().dataTable();
}.on('didInsertElement')
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#method__